# Calculate Area Element on a Prolate Spheroid's Surface

Tags: calculus, integration, geometry, differential-geometry, surfaces

I am trying to calculate a partial surface of a prolate spheroid in terms of the polar and azimuthal angles. I have been searching the internet for quite some time, but without finding a solution or an idea how to solve it that I understood.
So, here is what I think is the closest I got to a solution.

The general form of a spheroid:
$$\frac{x^2+y^2}{a^2}+\frac{z^2}{c^2}=1$$ with $c>a$ making it prolate.
It can be parameterised in the following form
$$x=a \> \cos(\phi) \> \sin(\theta)$$
$$y=a \> \sin(\phi) \> \sin(\theta)$$
$$z=c \> \cos(\theta)$$
with $\phi \in [0, 2\pi]$ and $\theta \in [0, \pi]$.
If I determine the coefficients of the first fundamental form $S = \int_{\phi_0}^{\phi_1}d\phi\int_{\theta_0}^{\theta_1}\sqrt{EG-F^2} \> d\theta$, they turn out to be
$$E = a^2 \> \sin^2(\theta)$$
$$F = 0$$
$$G = \frac{a^2+c^2+(a^2-c^2) \> \cos(2 \> \theta)}{2}$$
This was actually the approach as described on Wolfram Mathworld for a general [spheroid](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Spheroid.html). If the coefficients are plugged into the above equation for $S$, it results in $$S = \frac{a}{\sqrt{2}}\int_{\phi_0}^{\phi_1}d\phi\int_{\theta_0}^{\theta_1}\sqrt{a^2+c^2+(a^2-c^2) \> \cos(2 \> \theta)}\>\sin(\theta) \> d\theta$$
This equation can also be found on [Wolfram](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/OblateSpheroid.html), but is said to be the conventional form for the oblate spheroid ($a>c$). Apparently, the integral $\int_{\theta_0}^{\theta_1}\sqrt{a^2+c^2+(a^2-c^2) \> \cos(2 \> \theta)}\>\sin(\theta) \> d\theta$ can be solved to $$\dfrac{-c^2\ln\left(\left|c\sqrt{\left(a^2-c^2\right)\cos^2\left(x\right)+c^2}+\sqrt{a^2-c^2}\left|c\right|\cos\left(x\right)\right|\right)-c\sqrt{a^2-c^2}\cos\left(x\right)\sqrt{\frac{\left(a^2-c^2\right)\cos^2\left(x\right)}{c^2}+1}}{\sqrt{2}\sqrt{a-c}\sqrt{c+a}}$$
This works well indeed for oblate spheroids. I used the [ke!san Online Calculator](https://keisan.casio.com/exec/system/1311572253) to confirm.

Now, what do I have to do differently to find a similar function $S(\phi, \theta)$ for a prolate spheroid? Simply flipping $c$ and $a$ did not seem to do the trick. The parameterisation will stay the same as it is independent of the ratio of $c$ and $a$. Therefore, the fundamental coefficients should change neither.

I hope you can push me in the right direction. Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Please visit [this page](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Ellipsoid.html) and have a look at the formula for the area of an ellipsoid.

Comment: @YNK: Thank you for your comment.

There are three approaches for the surface area of an ellipsoid at your link, equations (17-22), (23+24), and (25-27). Did you intend to point me at a particular one?

I assume, I may set $a = b$ to account for a spheroid instead of the general ellipsoid. But three approaches also include $\sqrt(a^2 - c^2)$, which will not solve for a prolate spheroid with $c > a$. How can I take that into account?

Comment: I expected to divert your attention to the equation (27). Because this integral has no $\sqrt{a^2-c^2}$ term in it, I thought that it can be used regardless of $c \gt a$ or $c \lt a$ to determine the sought surface area of both prolate and oblate spheroid. Now I know I was mistaken, because once integrated, $\sqrt{a^2-c^2}$ term appears at several places in the formula for the mentioned area. I apologize.

Comment: Check out [this paper](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00190-022-01606-z), specifically eq. (57) and the mention of prolate ellipsoid below eq. (56).

Comment: @ChuckBatson: Thank you for pointing me at that extensive paper. I will read it and see if I can derive a solution for my problem.